# Modifying a variable class attribute

Tags: class, python-3.x

I'm trying to modify a class attribute based on the argument given. I'm just getting into python but I can't seem to find a way to do it without using a dictionary. Is there a pythonic way to do this?  See example below

```
class Ship:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        ship_type = {"schooner": [50, 30, 18],
            "galleon": [30, 14, 14]
        }
        self.max_weight = ship_type[name][0]
        self.speed = ship_type[name][1]
        self.poopdeck = ship_type[name][2]

    def upgrade(self, attribute, value):
        self.attribute += value


Someship.ship.upgrade(speed, 10)
```

I can write out a different method for each attribute but I feel as if there has to be something like this.
I apologize in advance if this has already been answered but I couldn't word it right if there is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the update method to update an existing attribute by using the [builtin functions](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) `hasattr()`, `setattr()` and `getattr()`.

```
def upgrade(self, attribute, value):
  if hasattr(self, attribute):
    setattr(self, attribute, getattr(self, attribute) + value )
  else:
    raise AttributeError("Can't upgrade non-existent attribute '{}'.".format(attribute))
```

Note that I'd also use the `__dict__` attribute to make setting up your instances easier:

```
class Ship:
  # types is a class variable, and will be the same for all instances,
  # and can be referred to by using the class. ie `Ship.types`
  types = {
    "schooner": {'weight':50, 'speed':30, 'poopdeck':18},
    "galleon": {'weight':30, 'speed':14, 'poopdeck':14},
    "default": {'weight':11, 'speed':11, 'poopdeck':11}
  }
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    # we update the instance dictionary with values from the class description of ships
    # this means that instance.speed will now be set, for example.
    if name in Ship.types:
      self.__dict__.update(Ship.types[name]) 
    else:
      self.__dict__.update(Ship.types["default"])

  def upgrade(self, attribute, value):
    if hasattr(self, attribute):
      setattr(self, attribute, getattr(self, attribute) + value )
    else:
      raise AttributeError("Can't upgrade non-existent attribute '{}'.".format(attribute))

ship = Ship("schooner")
print(ship.speed) #=> 30
ship.upgrade("speed", 10)
print(ship.speed) #=> 40
```

Comment: Holy crap.  Awesome.  This even shows me some other cool stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `setattr` and `getattr` functions. Your `upgrade` method can be implemented as

```
def upgrade(self, attribute, value):
    setattr(self, attribute, getattr(self, attribute) + value )
```

Comment: It crashes at the same point for me.  When I try to call:
    Someship.ship.upgrade(speed, 10)

it says speed is not defined
Thanks for the help by the way

Comment: You need to pass the attribute name as a string: `Someship.ship.upgrade('speed', 10)`. Or, pass a variable whose value is an attribute name: `attr='speed'; Someship.ship.upgrade(attr, 10)`.